# Compiling for rx600 with gcc

Tags: c, gcc, cross-compiling

I have a project that compiles for an RX600 with renasas' gcc compiler (from now on rx-elf-gcc). But I was wondering, shouldn't I be able to compile it with standard gcc? And if, how?

I'm making a docker container for the project, and I would prefere if I did not have to install renesas' compiler, installing it and supplying the activation code, etc.

I have found this piece of documentation, that got me started
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.3.0/gcc/RX-Options.html

I then expected to be able to do something like:

```
$ gcc -mcpu=rx600 -mlittle-endian-data dummy.c
```

But it gives the error:

```
gcc: warning: ‘-mcpu=’ is deprecated; use ‘-mtune=’ or ‘-march=’ instead
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mlittle-endian-data’
```

I have tried using -mtune instead, but it seems rx is not a valid option

```
$ gcc -mtune=rx600 dummy.c
cc1: error: bad value (‘rx600’) for ‘-mtune=’ switch
cc1: note: valid arguments to ‘-mtune=’ switch are: nocona core2 nehalem corei7 westmere sandybridge corei7-avx ivybridge core-avx-i haswell core-avx2 broadwell skylake skylake-avx512 bonnell atom silvermont slm knl intel x86-64 eden-x2 nano nano-1000 nano-2000 nano-3000 nano-x2 eden-x4 nano-x4 k8 k8-sse3 opteron opteron-sse3 athlon64 athlon64-sse3 athlon-fx amdfam10 barcelona bdver1 bdver2 bdver3 bdver4 znver1 btver1 btver2 generic
```

So, can I add a new hardware model to my installation? Or will these models just simply redirect my to rx-elf-gcc?

As a side note:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) 7.3.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ rx-elf-gcc --version
rx-elf-gcc (GCC_Build_20180315) 4.8.4.201801-GNURX
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

And the following works:

```
$ rx-elf-gcc -mcpu=rx600 -mlittle-endian-data -c dummy.c
```

Comment: `gcc` is the native compiler frontend program, which targets your *local* host system. GCC cross-compilers should always be prefixed with target information (like the `rx-elf-` prefix).

Comment: You should be able to download the [sources](https://gcc-renesas.com/rx/rx-latest-source-code/), rip out any silly activation stuff from the open source parts (optlib is Renesas' own proprietary stuff), and [compile your own](https://gcc-renesas.com/wiki/index.php?title=How_to_build_the_RX_Toolchain_under_Ubuntu_14.04) GCC for the Renesas RX targets.

Comment: Thanks you both for the inputs. My colleague took over the task and compiled the compiler. Nominal Animal, can you post you comment as an answer?